# Having trouble on importing jpg image (Java)

Tags: java, eclipse, 2d

Hello I am having trouble importing an image from another class.

> The error states " 'ImageLoader' cannot be resolved"

and the file name is correct.  My constructors that I am using are public and I don't know what else to change.

This is the line that's causing the error in my `"Game.java"` file (more specificly the `"ImageLoader"`):

```
testImage = ImageLoader.LoadImage("/textures/Hello.jpg");
```

This is in my `"ImageLoader.java"` file that that line is grabbing from:

```
package Graphix;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class ImageLoader {

    public static BufferedImage laodImage(String path){
        try {
        return ImageIO.read(ImageLoader.class.getResource(path));
    } catch (IOException e){
           e.printStackTrace();
           System.exit(1);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: is the file a local file? if so you need to define its locality like `testImage = ImageLoader.LoadImage("file:textures\\Hello.jpg");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo in your method name

```
 public static BufferedImage laodImage(String path)
```

should be changed to:

```
 public static BufferedImage loadImage(String path)
```

Also change your method call to:

```
testImage = ImageLoader.loadImage("/textures/Hello.jpg");
```

Method names should start with a lowercase letter in java.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that ImageLoader is in the same folder as the class loading the images or import the Graphix package

```
import Graphix.ImageLoader;
```

Answer (score 0):

try following code...

**Sample Code**

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LoadImageDemo{
    BufferedImage image = null;
    int width;
    int height;
    public LoadImageDemo() {
        File inputImg = new File("\\textures\\Hello.jpg");
        try {
            image = ImageIO.read(inputImg);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        int count = 0;
        for(int i=0; i<height; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<width; j++){
               count++;
               Color c = new Color(image.getRGB(j, i));
               System.out.println("S.No: " + count + " Red: " + c.getRed() +"  Green: " + c.getGreen() + " Blue: " + c.getBlue());
            }
         }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new LoadImageDemo();
    }

}
```

When you execute the above example, it would print the pixels of image

if you want to draw image so you can follow this link. 
[Drawing Image Click me](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/drawimage.html)